# SQL Assertion: The manager complex

Tags: sql, assertions

I have the following schema:

Emp(**eid** int, ename varchar(50), salary float, email varchar(80))

Works(**eid** int, **did** int, pct_time float)

Dept(**did** int, budget float, managerid int)

eid is for employee id.
did is for department id.
I've bolded primary keys.
managerid is a foreign key, as well as eid and did in Works.

Now, I'd like to add a "manager complex" assertion that ensure a manager will always have a higher salary than any employee that he/she manages.

Here's what I've been thinking:

```
CREATE ASSERTION managerComplex
CHECK
( NOT EXISTS (SELECT  M.salary  
              FROM Dept D, Emp M 
              WHERE D.managerid = M.eid) <= 
                                           (SELECT E.salary
                                            FROM Works W, Emp E
                                            WHERE W.eid = E.eid) AND
                                                                     D.did = W.did);
```

Is this even close to right?
Also, maybe I should have just made a couple CHECKs instead of an insertion?
I feel like multiple CHECKs is sloppier but would probably be easier to get right.

EDIT: The main reason I am asking is because I don't know if I'm correctly understanding NOT EXISTS

Comment: You've got 2 `salary float` columns in `Emp`. Did you mean to specify a different column instead of the second one or did you just miss the fact that you'd already included that column?

Comment: Oops, was just a typo, fixing it now

Comment: It might help to know what flavor of SQl you are using. Certainly there are no such things as assertions in SQl server.

Comment: Using mySQL 5.2 I believe. I turned in the homework today, but I'd still like to know whether this is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ...)` to be true, the `SELECT ...` must return no results.

You want to create a `SELECT` statement that will return any employee with a salary higher than the manager listed for the department(s) they work for. See if you can write that query, and then place it inside the `NOT EXISTS`

I'm not entirely sure what you wrote is even valid SQL, but it's certainly not what you want. I have a potential answer for you, but as this was marked homework, I'd like to attempt to prod you in the right direction before providing a complete answer.

---

As OP said the homework has been turned in...

```
CREATE ASSERTION managerComplex
CHECK
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT E.salary
             FROM Emp M, Dept D, Works W, Emp E
             WHERE M.eid = D.managerid AND 
                   W.did = D.did AND
                   E.eid = W.eid AND
                   E.salary > M.salary))
```

My `NOT EXISTS` has a query inside of it, that will return results if there are any employee salaries higher than their respective manager's salary. I look at all employees who work for a department, and only pull them into the result set if their salary is higher than the manager for that department's salary.

I'm not even sure your SQL is valid, as you have a `(SELECT ...) <= (SELECT ...) AND ...`. Comparing result sets with a `<=` doesn't make any sense to me. It's possible that's just SQL I've never used, but... I've never used it.

Comment: Hey Sam,
"See if you can write that query, and then place it inside the NOT EXISTS"
Isn't this what I've done? I found all the manager salaries (M.salary) and compared them to all the employee salaries that are in the same department... Ah man, I'm comparing the manager salary to itself, therefore it must be equal and therefore this assertion will also be invalid. Blah!

Comment: I'll update my answer with what I would use, and then provide an explanation, as you said you already had to turn the homework in.

Comment: @Sam is right that your syntax is not valid. To use a `(SELECT ...) <= (SELECT ...)` both subselects have to return one row only. Yours can return more than one.

Comment: You may also want to check this link, with an example, identical as your homework: [Fundamentals of Database Systems, Elvasri and Navathe, chapter 9](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3113085/1/Chapter-9-3):  `CREAT ASSERTION SALARY_CONSTRAINTCHECK (NOT EXISTS (SELECT *FROM EMPLOYEE E, EMPLOYEE M, DEPARTMENT DWHERE E.SALARY > M.SALARY ANDE.DNO=D.NUMBER AND D.MGRSSN=M.SSN))`

Comment: @ypercube Just a note, as you used the word identical, that example doesn't have the many-to-many employee-department relationship that OP's homework does.

Comment: @Sam: You are right, my mistake. It's only similar, not identical.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are close. My edit to your trial:

```
CREATE ASSERTION managerComplex
CHECK
( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
               FROM Dept D, Emp M 
               WHERE D.managerid = M.eid
                 AND M.salary < ANY
                               ( SELECT E.salary
                                 FROM Works W, Emp E
                                 WHERE W.eid = E.eid 
                                   AND D.did = W.did
                                   AND M.eid <> E.eid
                               )
             )
)
```